# Angular - RxJS - Observable and method return

Tags: angular, methods, rxjs

I have a method in my Angular 9 application which looks like this:

```
createTitleHTMLText(calendarEventObject: CalendarEventObject): string { 
this.translateService.get(calendarEventObject.calendarEventTyp).subscribe((res: string) => {
  const title = '<span><b>' + calendarEventTyp + '</b></span>;
  return title;
});
```

}

This method should return a string but how to do it - to get the translation I need an Observable and the further code has to be in der Observable - result block.
Actually I don't know how to do it - is there a way to synchronize Observables or what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right you have an Observable which emits a string, e.g. an http call to a remote service that returns (asynchronously) a string. In your case the service is `this.translateService.get(calendarEventObject.calendarEventTyp)`.

Then you have a method, `createTitleHTMLText(calendarEventObject: CalendarEventObject)`, which invokes the service and you would like this method to return the string emitted by the asynchronous service.

If this is what you want, you simply can not achieve it. The reason is that the service is asynchronous.

What you may want to explore is a solution along these lines

```
createTitleHTMLText(calendarEventObject: CalendarEventObject): Observable<string> { 
  this.translateService.get(calendarEventObject.calendarEventTyp).pipe(
     map((res:   string) =>. '<span><b>' + calendarEventTyp + '</b></span>')
  )
}
```

In this version, `createTitleHTMLText` function returns an Observable to whoever is interested. Such Observable can actually be subscribed where needed, maybe using the Angular `async` template pipe.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear at the moment. You are subscribing to the HTTP request but not using it's result. What is the value of `res` here? Nevertheless I guess what you need is the following

```js
createTitleHTMLText(calendarEventObject: CalendarEventObject): string { 
  this.translateService.get(calendarEventObject.calendarEventTyp).subscribe((res: string) => {
    return '<span><b>' + res + '</b></span>';
  });
}
```

Comment: Sry for the bad explanation - it was hard for me to explain. if I do it like in your example I get the following compiler message:  function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value - and I will avoid this message

Comment: How and where are you planning to use the value returned from this function?

Answer (score 0):

I use it like in this example:

```
fetchEvents(): void {
  this.events$ = this.datechoiceService.getPreparedCalendarEventsOfUser(this.user.id, this.view, this.viewDate)
 .pipe(
   map(results => {
     return results.map((calendarEventObject: CalendarEventObject) => {
      let calendarEvent: CalendarEvent<{ calendarEvent: CalendarEvent<any>; }> = {
        id: calendarEventObject.id,
        actions: this.actions,
        start: new Date(calendarEventObject.startsAt),
        end: new Date(calendarEventObject.endsAt),
        title: this.createTitleHTMLText(calendarEventObject),
        ...
      };
      return calendarEvent;
     })
   })
 );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an observable into promise and you can use async / await,

```
async createTitleHTMLText(calendarEventObject: CalendarEventObject): string {
    const calendarEventTyp = await this.translateService.get(calendarEventObject.calendarEventTyp).toPromise();
    return '<span><b>' + calendarEventTyp + '</b></span>';
}
```

Comment: This probably returns a `Promise<string>` not a `string`.

Comment: No, It doesn't, Please check this guide:
https://www.techiediaries.com/javascript-async-await-tutorial/

Comment: If you refer to the `fetchData()` method mentioned towards the end of the guide, that method actually returns a `Promise` as you can check in the [example code of the guide](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-async-await?file=src/app/app.component.ts)